# Node.js Cannot pass function to Redis operations

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis

I am using node.js to store a simple unduplicated list to redis and retrive it.

However, when I trying to check the result like this, the console will not log anything

```
client.sAdd('frameworks_set',['ReactJS', 'Angular', 'Svelte', 'VueJS', 'VueJS'],function(err, reply){
    console.log("retieved"+ reply)});

client.sMembers('frameworks_set',function(err, reply){
    console.log("retieved"+ reply)
});
```

I can see that my list has been added to redis successfully but not sure how would I retrieve the list back to node.js now

```
127.0.0.1:6379> smembers frameworks_set
1) "Angular"
2) "Svelte"
3) "VueJS"
4) "ReactJS"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

either `await` the promise or use `.then`

```js
// using `await`
await client.sAdd('frameworks_set',['ReactJS', 'Angular', 'Svelte', 'VueJS', 'VueJS']);
const reply = await client.sMembers('frameworks_set');

// using `.then`
client.sAdd('frameworks_set',['ReactJS', 'Angular', 'Svelte', 'VueJS', 'VueJS']).then(() => {
  return client.sMembers('frameworks_set');
}).then(reply => {
  // ...
});
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise